# Decorate an object in JavaScript and expose same signature

Tags: javascript, decorator

Given two classes:

```
function Example(){
this.methodOne = function(/* some args */){...};
this.methodTwo = function(/* some args */){...};
this.methodThree = function(/* some args*/){...};
}

function ExampleWrapper(example){
this.functionFour = function(...){...};    
this.wrapped = example;
}
```

Where ExampleWrapper gets an instance of Example and wraps it to get further functionality (decorator pattern).

I'd like to be able to call each function of Example, from an instance of ExampleWrapper, without the need of defining each function manually.
I mean, i could do, for each function in Example, the following in ExampleWrapper

```
function ExampleWrapper(example){
...
this.methodOne = function(/* some args */){
    return this.wrapped.methodOne(/* same some args*/);
}
...
}
```

and then

```
var ex = new Example();
var wrap = new ExampleWrapper(ex);
wrap.methodOne(...)
```

but that is not very escalable/neat.

So, how could i achive that? [Guess reflection may be the way to go, but im not used to work with it yet]

Comment: You might want to look at [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). But first check if they are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=proxy) where you need your code to run.

Comment: What about `Object.setPrototypeOf` between the two instances?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to extend prototype ?

```
function Example(){
}
Example.prototype.methodOne = function(/* some args */){console.log('1')};
Example.prototype.methodTwo = function(/* some args */){console.log('2')};
Example.prototype.methodThree = function(/* some args*/){console.log('3')};

function ExampleWrapper(example){
   this.functionFour = function(...){...};    
   this.wrapped = example;
}

ExampleWrapper.prototype = Example.prototype;

var test = new ExampleWrapper(new Example());
test.functionFour();
test.methodOne(...);
```

Comment: `Object.create` or `Object.setPrototypeOf` between two instances could be a better choice as it also handles instance methods (rather than prototype methods in your approach).

Comment: Like this ? var test = Object.setPrototypeOf(new ExampleWrapper(), new Example());

Can you provide a sample of use of Object.setPrototypeOf, for my information please ?

Comment: It could even be `Object.setPrototypeOf( wrap, ex )`, in OP's example. The drawback is that `wrap` of course can't have two prototypes, `ex` and `ExampleWrapper` at the same time, so it's either my way or yours.

Comment: Thank's for the explanation :)